# foreach loop with strings from a database

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach

I am trying to read multiple strings from a database and do a foreach string in (the strings I get from the database) Loop. To give you a better idea: here's the method. (I have declared the connection before.)

```
private void PendingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string PendingQuery = "SELECT user_from FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to=@username";
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand PendingCommand = new MySqlCommand(PendingQuery, connection);
        PendingCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", CurrentUserUsername);
        MySqlDataReader PendingDataReader = PendingCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (PendingDataReader.Read())
        {
            foreach (string senderusername in PendingDataReader.GetString("user_from").ToString())
            {
                //go on from here
            }

        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

it selects the `user_from` from the table `friend_requests` where `user_to`=thecurrentuser's username. The thing is there are multiple strings. I want to do a foreach string in the database where user_to=thecurrentuser's username

[image]

in this example, i would do the loop 4 times and the strings would be Aluin,test123,XeKe,milanneke10

How do I go about this?

Comment: You don't need to `foreach` over anything. Each record you get via `PendingDataReader.Read()` is a single string. Are you seeing something different when you debug?

Comment: What do you mean ? i'm sorry i'm verry amature when it comes to codes i've only been studying it for a coupple of months . I need the friend request to show up so i can make a xaml object for each string i get

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code, and see what the value of `PendingDataReader.GetString("user_from")` is. [Here's how to do that in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @RubenVersavel Can you not just assign to your variable from the reader `var senderusername = PendingDataReader.GetString("user_from")` - this should execute until there is anything to read

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius That will only give me one string at the end no ? the last one that has been read  ?

Comment: Don't `ToString` on a column directly, `DBNull.Value` will cause an exception to be thrown, you should ensure the value isn't null before changing to string.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use `foreach`? The `while` loop is all you should need.

Comment: @NetMage I think im using hte foreach loop too early . What i need is to store all the strings that the reader returns. then do a foreachloop for all these strings. my plan is to make a grid with items in it foreach string and have a button to accept or decline the friend request .

Comment: @RubenVersavel it won't because you are already in a while loop, so each time it will read the next row

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius How do i use the values then ? after the while loop i need to do a foreach string of the strings i've read and make a grid with a label that has the name of the sender in it and a accapt and decline button in it

Comment: @RubenVersavel You could make a grid in the `while` loop exactly the same way as in a `foreach` loop or you could just accept @TomFarley's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a List to hold all of the values.

```
List<string> dataCollection = new List<string>();

while(PendingDataReader.Read())
{
    dataCollection.Add(PendingDataReader.GetString("user_from"));
}
```

Comment: @RufusL You're right, a dictionary is just the first thing that popped into my head because I was recently working with a database with unique index keys. I changed the code to use the List class instead, which should allow the OP to do what he needs.

Comment: @RubenVersavel The updated code using the `List(T)` class should solve this issue

Comment: This works perfectly , i can use the foreach loop after the while with the list . Thanks a bunch !